# Part of my script is causing failure to execute the function. replaceText works in all other places, but when I add this one then nothing works

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have many replacetext clauses that execute perfectly until I add this one. When I add it, it gives no error and says that the function executed correctly but it didn't produce the document as it's supposed to. Without this clause the function executes by replacing all the text and then saving a copy of the auto filled file in Google Drive. It gets the text from a Google sheet every time a new Form is submitted and a new Form responses entry is received.

There are 2 differences between the below replaceText and all the other ReplaceTexts: 
1. It's data in the Google Sheet gets stored like this: **Tax Return, Supporting Documents, Bookkeeping, Business TAX Returns** where others have no commas because it's the only Checkbox type question in the Form where the others are multiple choice or short answers. 
2. The place where the Text is being replaced in the doc is bulleted, but I have tried to run it without the bullets and it didn't execute either.

Not sure if you need the bit of code itself so I'm adding it for in case:

```
body.replaceText("{{servicesPTY}}", servicesPTY);
```

Comment: Did you check StackDriver for the execution log?

Comment: Yes, it says *running* for a very long time and then *completed*

Comment: And the string you are trying to replace is stored in the variable `servicesPTY` ? So it is constantly changing? Can you give an example of such a string?

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#replacetextsearchpattern,-replacement), first parameter of `replaceText()` should be regular expression and I don't think that `{{servicesPTY}}` is a supported regex pattern.

Take a look to the it:

> This methods uses Google's [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2) regular expression library, which limits the [supported syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

Answer (score 0):

I just ran this myself.  Evidently no need for a regex at all.  I wasn't really sure because I don't use Google Docs that much.

```
const servicesPTY="some text";
body.replaceText('{{serveicesPTY}}',servicesPTY);
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here. At the moment the variable is identified by the 117th column: `var servicesPTY = e.values[117];` with the event (e) being triggered by a new form submission. I'm not sure how to identify the variable with `var re=new RegExp('\\{\\{servicesPTY\\}\\}','g');`

Comment: That's just a different way to generate the pattern in a regex.  I presume that you have this string in the body text `{{servicesPTY}}`

Comment: The brackets are use in regex so I think that they have to be escaped.

Comment: Yes, all the parts that gets replaced are in curly brakets like `{{FullNames}}` or `{{servicesPTY}}` . How do I escape them though?

Comment: You don’t have to escape the pattern in the text you have to escape the pattern in the refectory